# How to use strings in C?

Tags: c, string

I am trying to learn how to write modern programs. I want to store binary data in strings and then output it. Why? For example I want to read a whole file to a string and then output it to stdout.

How can I do it? Printf and puts stop outputting data after the first \0

And what should I use to store filenames so I can work with international characters? wchar_t?

Comment: You shouldn't store binary data as a string, because of problems like \0 is the terminating string. Store the bytes in `uint8_t` arrays or `unsigned char` arrays, but do not treat them as strings. Also when you read a binary file, many bytes are just not printable and if you print  them, you will get "garbage" on the screen. It's better to print the hex representation of the bytes.

Comment: @Pablo Okay, but I can't print to stdout an array of uint8_t using puts or printf

Comment: no you can: `printf("%.*s", str_len, str_ptr);`

Comment: If you insist on printing gobbledygook to your terminal, (1) it's not actually a string, but (2) you can use `fwrite` to write arbitrary data to stdout as long as you remember how much data you have (because, again, it's not a string...there's no `arbitrarydatalen` function, and there can't be).

Comment: When dealing with binary stream, it's better to print them in hex format, and you can use `printf` for that: `printf("%02x\n", val);`

Comment: "How to use strings in C?"  .. This is not how you use strings in C. Strings are character arrays of printable characters terminated with `NUL`, binary data does not have to fit that format at all.

Comment: @yano actually by definition, a string is a linear sequence of data, not necessarily characters.

Comment: @machine_1 C library specifies   "A _string_ is a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null character."  Seems   to necessitate _characters_.

Comment: @chux Yeah fine, but I meant the general meaning of the word.

Comment: @yano a character must not be printable to be part of a string. `"Hello\r\b"` is a valid string with 2 non-printable characters.

Comment: @Pablo Carriage return and backspace? I consider those are printable whitespace characters. Printable characters are the only practical contents for C strings and their associated functions. Anything else, use a byte array.

Comment: I meant `\a` (BELL), not `\b`. I don't consider them printable, `\r` has no representation at all, the terminal puts the cursor at the beginning of the line, but it doesn't have to, it may as well ignore that. Same with BELL.

Comment: *"I want to read a whole file to a string and then output it to stdout."* There is nothing preventing you from doing that. You can easily get the file size with `stat` or with `fseek` and allocate a buffer sufficient for the file and the `fread` the file (or just `mmap` it) and write the buffer to `stdout` -- the problem is just as @Pablo describes. The file may contain characters that are not printable (e.g. values less than decimal `32` (space) or greater than `127` (`'~'`).. So you need to determine how to handle the output.

Comment: @Pablo No, I don't consider a BELL to be printable. And I've used exactly 0 BELLs in my C strings throughout my entire career. That goes for single backspaces and carriage returns as well. Argue the pedantics of my comment if you want, but there is no practical purpose to put anything but printable characters in a C string, which is the whole concept the OP needs to understand.

Comment: @yano I agree that having non printable characters in a string is not practical, but that doesn't make a sequence of chars as I posted less of a string. I also agree, arguing about that does not help the OP.

Comment: @Pablo fair enough, I agree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say  you have a binary file. Let's say you want to read 8 bytes from the
file.

```
FILE *fp = fopen("a", "rb");

if(fp == NULL)
    return;

unsigned char bytes[8];
if(fread(bytes, sizeof bytes / sizeof *bytes, 1, fp) != 1)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "could not read 8 bytes\n");
    return;
}

// printing the bytes:

for(size_t i = 0; i < sizeof bytes / sizeof *bytes; ++i)
    printf("%02X ", bytes[i]);

puts("");

fclose(fp);
```

I run this code reading the compiled binary (filename is `a`) of this same code, the first 8
bytes are:

```
7F 45 4C 46 02 01 01 00
```

As you can see there are bytes that have no representation and if I would print
that as a string, this would be the result:

[image]

which is less helpful, here I was lucky that there were at least printable
integers.

And if you want to have also the printable characters printed as as well (like hex editors
do):

```
size_t n;
// yes I swapped the number of items and the number of bytes here
// for reading the whole file
while((n = fread(bytes, 1, sizeof bytes / sizeof *bytes, fp)))
{
    size_t i;
    for(i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        printf("%02X ", bytes[i]);

    // if less than array size bytes read, to align output
    printf("%*s", (int) ((sizeof bytes / sizeof *bytes) - i)*3, "");
    printf("%10s |", "");

    for(i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        if(isprint(bytes[i])) 
            printf("%c", bytes[i]);
        else
            printf(".");
    }

    // same here as above
    printf("%*s", (int) ((sizeof bytes / sizeof *bytes) - i), "");
    puts("|");
}
```

This outputs:

```
7F 45 4C 46 02 01 01 00            |.ELF....|
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00            |........|
03 00 3E 00 01 00 00 00            |..>.....|
A0 07 00 00 00 00 00 00            |........|
40 00 00 00 00 00 00 00            |@.......|
F0 23 00 00 00 00 00 00            |.#......|
00 00 00 00 40 00 38 00            |....@.8.|
09 00 40 00 23 00 22 00            |..@.#.".|
...
00 6C 69 62 63 2E 73 6F            |.libc.so|
2E 36 00 66 6F 70 65 6E            |.6.fopen|
00 70 75 74 73 00 5F 5F            |.puts.__|
73 74 61 63 6B 5F 63 68            |stack_ch|
6B 5F 66 61 69 6C 00 70            |k_fail.p|
75 74 63 68 61 72 00 70            |utchar.p|
72 69 6E 74 66 00 66 63            |rintf.fc|
6C 6F 73 65 00 5F 5F 63            |lose.__c|
74 79 70 65 5F 62 5F 6C            |type_b_l|
...
39 01 00 00 00 00 00 00            |9.......|
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00            |........|
01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00            |........|
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00            |........|
```

Comment: Very good.  Except `fread(bytes, sizeof bytes / sizeof *bytes, 1, fp) != 1` may be better as `fread(bytes, sizeof bytes, 1, fp) != 1`.

Comment: @chux, I though of just doing `sizeof bytes` because `sizeof *bytes` is 1 anyway, but I wanted to have the correct way of having the number of elements of an array regardless of the type. If you think that the answer is more clear with having only `sizeof bytes`, let me know so that I can update the answer.

Comment: @Pablo Thanks. The first example is what I want. I need to send binary files to stdout so other programs can read these binary data from stdin.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to store binary data in strings and then output it.

Once you have your binary data in a storage (in our case it is `char bin[]`)
you can make char ascii string out of it using `sprintf` :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){

    int i;  
    char bin[] = { 0, 1 , '1', '2', '3' , 0 , 7 }; 
    char str[256]; 
    char *buf2 = str;

    size_t size =  sizeof(bin)*2;

    for(i= 0; i < size; i++  )
    {
        buf2 += sprintf(buf2, "%02X", bin[i]);
    }

    str[i] = 0; // terminate your string

    printf("STRING: %s", str);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
STRING: 00013132330007
```